# Drupal 6: Creating blog post page with View Module [dynamic Path]

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, blogs

I'm a drupal newbie...

I created my blog post listing page with View. Everything is great...

but the post detail page is not like as I need. So I wanted to create that page as well with View Module, so I can control all content, etc... but how can I create that page? url changes according to post title. somehow I need to define a dynamic Path at view module page.

appreciate helps!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to want to use Views for that. You should look into creating template pages for whatever theme you are using so that you can customize the look. Here's a Drupal handbook page on blog pages specifically:
http://drupal.org/node/44699

Here's a book that covers front end theming for Drupal in-depth:
http://frontenddrupal.com/

Comment: i actually wanted to do as you advise. I used Drupal Themer module and it gave me node-blog.tpl.php as candidate name. and I created that file, but it didnt take effect at all. it didnt see that page :( and displayed as default although I created node-blog.tpl.php file :/ I cleared cache and re-defined,refreshed themes page as well. but no success :/

Comment: sorted :) http://mattmcman.us/article/why-isnt-drupal-recognizing-my-content-types-template

Comment: @artmania Yeah, glad you found the solution to the template showing up, I've been bitten by that before, those kind of things are easy to miss.